# JDBC transactions - Tomcat 7.0 and vFabric tc differences

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

Everyone.

I am working on some Java servlet with JDBC access to PostgreSQL DB. Application is using DataSource defined as resource in server's context. DataSource has auto commit property set to "false" - I am managing transactions from servlet.

In application I have following code:

```
String query = 
                "insert into auth_selling_permissions "
                + "(selling_permissions_key, "
                + "sell "
                + ") values ( "
                + " DEFAULT, "
                +  PermissionLevel.getIntegerValue(org.getSell())+") "
                + " returning selling_permissions_key";

        List<Map<String,Object>> list = this.template.queryForList(query);

        Integer outKey = (Integer)list.get(0).get("selling_permissions_key");
```

Within same transaction I am doing the following action:

```
for(Map<String,Object> prod : listProducts){
                Integer k = (Integer)prod.get("type_key");
                keysSection+="("+outKey+", "+k+"),";
            }
            if(keysSection.length()>0){
                keysSection = keysSection.substring(0, keysSection.length()-1);

                String bindingQuery = "insert into auth_selling_products_permissions (selling_permissions_key, type_key) values "+keysSection;
                this.template.update(bindingQuery);
            }
```

Code above is meant to insert a row to selling_permission table, get back newly generated key and, using it, fill related table (which uses selling_permission_key as FK).
As I mentioned, all is done within single transaction.

The problem is: I am using for developement STS with vFabric tc server. In dev environment it works great. But production env. uses Tomcat 7.0. When I am runnin my servlet on Tomcat 7 (using same database server, same JDBC driver and same definition of db resource) - it fails. It gives me org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException and tells that key, which I am trying to insert into auth_selling_products_permissions does not exist in auth_selling_permissions.

I am quite sure that the problem is on server level. But I have now idea why Tomcat behaves like that, and what should I check/configure/change to make it work as my dev tc server.

EDIT:

Resource definition:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/calc_webapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="dbuser" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prod_db" defaultAutoCommit = "false"/>
```

Exactly the same on both servers.

Comment: Did you copy the <Resource> entry from TC to Tomcat? If they're identical and behave different that would be interesting.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. Here is how it looks like:  
  
<Resource name="jdbc/calc_webapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="dbuser" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
               url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prod_db" defaultAutoCommit = "false"/>

Comment: you ever sort this issue out, or still occurring?

Comment: Still. I've checked if it's not a matter of server version or jdbc driver, but it's not, seems to be then just a configuration difference, but I didin't get time to go through all that stuff and check differencies. Anyway, still I have no idea what is going on...